# unaligned groupplot

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

I tried to stack my plots with a `groupplot` from `pgfplots` package. Like in this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
        group size=1 by 3,
        vertical sep=1ex
    },
    scale only axis=true,
    height=1.5cm, width=8cm,
    ticks=none]
    \nextgroupplot[axis y line=left,axis x line=none]
    \addplot[black, domain=0:360] {sin(x)};
    \nextgroupplot[axis y line=left,axis x line=none]
    \addplot[black, domain=0:360] {cos(x)};
    \nextgroupplot[axis y line=left,axis x line=bottom,xlabel=time]
    \addplot[black, domain=0:360] {cos(x)};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I don't understand why the plots aren't aligned/scaled in the same way:

[image: result/expected]

How can I get my plots aligned in the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying `domain` does not set the `xmin`, `xmax` etc. for the plot.
It simply sets the function evaluation domain and then afterwards the min/max limits are set from the data. Due to rounding errors you can expect to see the behaviour you have.

In general:

> Anytime you use `groupplots` and sharing axis domains you should specify `x/ymin` AND `x/ymax`.

So your code needs to look like this:

```
\begin{groupplot}[
   group style={
      group size=1 by 3,
      vertical sep=1ex
   },
   xmin=0,xmax=360,
   scale only axis=true,
   height=1.5cm, width=8cm,
   ticks=none]
....
```

Comment: Good to know. My real live data is now perfectly aligned!